# Most concise way to check whether a list is empty or contains only None?

Tags: python, list, types

Most concise way to check whether a list is empty or contains only None?

I understand that I can test:

```
if MyList:
    pass
```

and:

```
if not MyList:
    pass
```

but what if the list has an item (or multiple items), but those item/s are None:

```
MyList = [None, None, None]
if ???:
    pass
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way is to use [`all`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#all) and a list comprehension:

```
if all(e is None for e in myList):
    print('all empty or None')
```

This works for empty lists as well. More generally, to test whether the list only contains things that evaluate to `False`, you can use [`any`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#any):

```
if not any(myList):
    print('all empty or evaluating to False')
```

Comment: That is probably more efficient, yes, but using `==` is not *wrong*.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `all()` function to test is all elements are None:

```
a = []
b = [None, None, None]
all(e is None for e in a) # True
all(e is None for e in b) # True
```

Answer (score 4):

You can directly compare lists with `==`:

```
if x == [None,None,None]:

if x == [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned with elements in the list which evaluate as true:

```
if mylist and filter(None, mylist):
    print "List is not empty and contains some true values"
else:
    print "Either list is empty, or it contains no true values"
```

If you want to strictly check for `None`, use `filter(lambda x: x is not None, mylist)` instead of `filter(None, mylist)` in the `if` statement above.