# how to check whether list contains only None in python

Tags: python

```
l=[None,None]
```

is there a function that checks whether list l contains only None or not?

Comment: What should it return for empty list `[]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if all items in the list are None ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518394/how-to-check-if-all-items-in-the-list-are-none)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most concise way to check whether a list is empty or \[None\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270920/most-concise-way-to-check-whether-a-list-is-empty-or-none)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you mean, to check if the list `l` contains only None,

```
if all(x is None for x in l):
  ...
```

Comment: "...contains only None" OR is empty.

Comment: @systempuntoout, this is actually a generator expression.

Answer (score 36):

```
L == [None] * len(L)
```

is much faster than using all() when L *is* all None

```
$ python -m timeit -s'L=[None]*1000' 'all(x is None for x in L)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 276 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s'L=[None]*1000' 'L==[None]*len(L)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.2 usec per loop
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. A bit obscure!

Comment: A good answer, if performance is the main aim.
Else resort to using `all()` for readability purposes.

Comment: Des this work in python 3.9? I'm getting `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: @10Replies, I would expect that when working with numpy arrays/ the `all` and `any` that numpy provides. This answer is for a sequence of values that can be safely cast to bool and using the builtin `all` and `any`

Answer (score 17):

Try `any()` - it checks if there is a single element in the list which is considered `True` in a boolean context. `None` evaluates to `False` in a boolean context, so `any(l)` becomes `False`.

Note that, to check if a list (and not its contents) is really `None`, `if l is None` must be used. And `if not l` to check if it is either None (or anything else that is considered `False`) or empty.

Comment: >>> any([None,None,0])
 will give False

Comment: How did I get this far without hearing of `any()`? Amazing.

Answer (score 6):

I personally prefer making a `set` and then verifying if it is equal to a set with one element `None`:

```
set(l) == {None}

assert set([None, None, None]) == {None}
assert set([None, 2, None])    != {None}
```

Not the fastest but still faster than the `all(...)` implementation:

```
$ python -m timeit -s'L=[None]*1000' 'all(x is None for x in L)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 59 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s'L=[None]*1000' 'set(L)=={None}'
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.7 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s'L=[None]*1000' 'L==[None]*len(L)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.17 usec per loop
```

Comment: Why the first one iterated 10k while others in 100k?

Comment: @mece1390 `timeit` chooses the number of loops to run at least for 0.2 seconds. Faster code => more loops needed. For more details check `autorange` out: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.autorange

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the members of the list are None, then you can loop over the items and check if they are None

If you want to check if list itself is None, you can use type(varlist) and it will return None

you can do

if (lst == None):
...     print "yes"

works.