# How to check if all items in the list are None?

Tags: python

```
In [27]: map( lambda f,p: f.match(p), list(patterns.itervalues()), vatids )
Out[27]: [None, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb73bfdb0>, None]
```

The list can be all `None` or one of it is an re.Match instance.
What one liner check can I do on the returned list to tell me that the contents are all `None`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check list is none in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583860/how-to-check-list-is-none-in-python)

Answer (score 257):

```
all(v is None for v in l)
```

will return `True` if all of the elements of `l` are `None`

Note that `l.count(None) == len(l)` is a lot faster but requires that `l` be an actual `list` and not just an iterable.

Comment: For the lazy ones: [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#all) is a link to the docs.

Comment: As far as first expression uses generator, does it stop at first `None` appearance?Also, why the 2nd expression is faster? Make no sense to me.

Comment: @s0upa1t [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) stops when it finds the first falsy object. The second is faster at least under CPython as the method `.count` on the objects of the `list` type is built-in and written in C and unlike the generator it doesn't have interpreter involved in the loop over the list.

Comment: Seconding Dan D. as  `all(v is None for v in l)` will return true if you have a `0` in-place of a `None`

Answer (score 85):

For the specific use case in the question, you can use

```
not any(my_list)
```

This returns `True` if all items of `my_list` are falsy. Since the only objects in your list are match objects and `None`s, and match objects are always trucy, this will give the same result as `all(x is None for x in my_list)`.  As demonstrated in [gnibbler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518394/how-to-check-if-all-items-in-the-list-are-none/6518751#6518751), using `not any(my_list)` is much faster.

Comment: This one fails for numeric values less than 1 which are considered falsy

Comment: They are? Surely only 0 and 0.0 are falsy.

Comment: @Sven, how is my comment irrelevant for the question? He asked about a function which can detect if a list only contains None values. Your example would handle [0, None] the same way as a list containg [None, None]. I see me mistake about negative numbers, I'm not sure where I've got this from!

Comment: Doesn't really check "if all the items in the list are None", but works (and is probably the nicest solution) for the actual example in the question (in which each item in the list will either be None or a match object, so this will indeed confirm that the list contains no matches)

Comment: @Dog: The question explains clearly that the list consists of return values of `re.match()` which are either `None` or a match object, so it simply does not matter that this solution would fail for `0`.  I added some explanation to make this clearer.

Comment: @Sven, great! Did not consider the whole question when I commented. Just reacted when I saw it were more than one condition which would yield True

Comment: @SvenMarnach This answer is completely wrong based on what OP was asking, downvoting.

Comment: @sleepycal: Thanks for letting me know.  Could you point out what exactly is wrong with this answer?  Checking the truth value of match objects is a documented and common pattern, and the expression in this answer gives the same result as `all(m is None for m in my_list)`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach OP explicitly asked for a solution which checks if all values are None, where as your code submission checks if they are "falsey".

Comment: @sleepycal:  No, that's only the information in the title.  The question in the body is more specific.  I gave a concise answer that perfectly fits the OPs use case of a list of match objects, and I explained what it does and why it works in this specific case.  If you think this is not helpful, I don't know what is.

Comment: Re-read his question. Both in the title AND the body, he explicitly asked "are all None", not "are all falsey".

Comment: @sleepycal: I generally try to give answers that solve people's problems, instead of answering exactly what they _think_ their problem is ("XY problem").  The question makes the actual problem quite clear (determine if none of the patterns in the list match), and my answer is a concise and fast solution to that problem.

Comment: Basically, empty string is not None so your answer is basically, wrong

Comment: @EvgeniMakarov It's a solution to the OP's problem. It might not be a solution to yours. In the code in the question, the items in the list can only be match objects (trucy) or `None` (falsy), so this answer does exactly what the OP asked for. I also explain the semantics in the answer. Calling this "wrong" completely misses the point. It's also a bit rude.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I'm not sure which my problem you mean. 
But, original question sounds like "How to check if all items in the list are None?"
And `not any(my_list)` is incorrect answer to this original question. It's not pythonic, at least, since list can be of any type

Comment: @gvm This is getting bizarre. Please read the question, including the body, then read my answer. I think everything has been said.

Comment: @SvenMarnach this is not getting bizzare. Even if the question, including the body, is saying something about types, you should not write unsafe functions in python, especially dedicated for potential reusability. Once you have a function named ```check_if_items_not_none``` later someone from your team can just import this function and use it in completely different context. So writing such functions, that behave completely unexpected on various potential types is such a nightmare practice that should be avoided and moreover, banned for production!

Comment: @gvm Which is why I'd never write such a function, nor did I ever suggest doing so.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I think it can be somehow mentioned in the answer. Because not all community members can precisely read the description of the question, which is most likely indexed in search engines only by the title. And can copy-paste to their codebase some "shorter form code".

Comment: @gvm That's fair. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 21):

Since Match objects are never going to evaluate to false, it's ok and much faster to just use `not any(L)`

```
$ python -m timeit -s"L=[None,None,None]" "all( v is None for v in L )"
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.52 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s"L=[None,None,None]" "not any(L)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.281 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s"L=[None,1,None]" "all( v is None for v in L )"
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.81 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s"L=[None,1,None]" "not any(L)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.272 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 8):

Or a bit weird but:

```
a = [None, None, None]
set(a) == set([None])
```

OR:

```
if [x for x in a if x]: # non empty list
    #do something
```

EDITED:

```
def is_empty(lVals):
    if not lVals:
        return True
    for x in lVals:
        if x:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Both of these need to iterate over the whole list even if the 1st element is not None.

Comment: @gnibbler - yes, you are right, added one more 'ugly' solution that would not iterate through all items

Comment: A more succinct definition of `is_empty(my_list)` would be `return not any(my_list)`.  At the very least, you should omit the first two lines.

Comment: @Sven - yes - you are right, simply trying to not duplicate other solution but provide the same functionality. I know that it was already discussed and 'all' method is a guru way)) but i am not a guru - i am simply learning new thing

Answer (score 2):

I managed to come up with an approach using `map` that hasn't been given yet

### tl;dr

```
def all_none(l):
    return not any(map(None.__ne__, l))

all_none([None, None, None]) # -> True
all_none([None, None, 8])    # -> False
```

### explanation

The use of `None.__ne__` is bit weirder than you'd expect at first glance. This method returns a `NotImplementedType` object when given something that isn't None.

You'd be hoping that `NotImplemented` would be a stand-in for `False`, however it's truthy too! This means that using `None.__eq__` across a collection will produce thruthy values for everything.

```
list(map(None.__eq__, [None, None, 8]))
# -> [True, True, NotImplemented]

all(list(map(None.__eq__, [None, None, 8])))
# -> True
```

From the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines
> either a **bool**() method that returns False or a **len**() method
> that returns zero

Instead, `None.__ne__` returns `False` for any `None` elements, and a
`NotImplementedType` object for anything else:

```
list(map(None.__ne__, [None, None, 8]))
# -> [False, False, NotImplemented]
```

Using this, you can check if `any` elements are not `None` which will return `True`. I like to think of this as 2 separate methods if that helps with the mental negation gymnastics.

```
def contains_truthy(l):
    return any(map(None.__ne__, l))

def all_none(l):
    return not contains_truthy(l)
```

I haven't done any benchmarking with this, but as mentioned by others in this thread, `not any` will produce fast results.

Answer (score 0):

```
is_all_none = lambda L: not len(filter(lambda e: not e is None, L))

is_all_none([None,None,'x'])
False
is_all_none([None,None,None])
True
```

Comment: aside from being very verbose compared to the standard answers, it baffles me why you would use `lambda` here instead of the simple `def`.

Comment: @RoundTower, because he asked for a one-liner. I made a guess he would use it as an inline function since he already used lambda's in his example.

Comment: @RoundTower  "baffles" ?  the _def_ is a few more lines by the time you include the requisite blank lines spaces surrounding functions.  I don't understand why python programmers do not care about code length bloat - it's a lot more screen real estate. We're not talking about condensing fifty lines into one a la' _perl_ code golf but also not expanding one or two lines into 5 or 10

Answer (score 0):

If you expect some items to not be `None`, then I would avoid looping through the entire list.

```
def check_none(l):
    for x in l:
        if not x is None:
            return False
    return True
```