# adding is_empty to hashtable

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashtable

I'm trying to add an is_empty(self) method. Which will return true if the hash table maps no keys to values, else false. 
This is what I have at the moment I'm just unsure how to approach the is_empty function using self.

```
class MyHashTable:

    def __init__(self, capacity): 
        self.capacity = capacity 
        self.slots = [None] * self.capacity

    def __str__(self): 
        return str(self.slots )

    def is_empty(self) 
        pass
```

Comment: It would probably be worth to implement [`__len__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) first, then you can use `len(table) == 0` (or just `if table: ...`) for empty checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `self.slots` is a `list`, and the goal is to test that all the elements are `None`. I would suggest:

```
def is_empty(self) 
   return self.slots.count(None) == len(self.slots)
```

See [How to check if all items in the list are None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518394/how-to-check-if-all-items-in-the-list-are-none) for my answer there and others.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can be using a built-in function called **all()**. You may check the [reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) for further detail.

```
Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).
```

Sample Code:

```
def is_empty(self) 
    return all(item is None for item in self.slots)
```

Comment: One stylistic issue: Comparing with ``None`` should be done by ``item is None``.