# How can i test two Variables on NoneType in Python 3?

Tags: python, if-statement

All the time I tried to compare two variables with type `None` but it doesn't work.

example:

```
if type(a and b) == type(None):
   #do something
else:
   #do other stuff
```

Does somebody know the right statement and an explanation?

Comment: `if a is None and b is None`...

Comment: In case you need to check more than 2 variables, you could put them in an iterable and then [check if all items in the list are None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518394/how-to-check-if-all-items-in-the-list-are-none).

Answer (score 2):

You can check differently.

```
if a is None and b is None:
    print('Both a and b are None')
else:
    print('a and b are not None')
```

Issues with your code.

1. `a and b` will return either `a` or `b`
2. type comparison is not a good option.

Comment: To be precise, `a and b` will return either `a` or `b`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, if you want to check for null variables, you should use the `x is None` syntax. There is only one instance of the None object in a Python runtime (it's called a singleton). Moreover, checking against type tends to be bad practice in general. In your case, you should do:

```
if a is None and b is None:
   #do something
else:
   #do other stuff
```

You can also simplify it to `if (a and b) is None`, since the and operator will propagate the None if one of a and b is None.

Answer (score 0):

```
def nonetype_check1(a,b):
    if a==b and a==None:           
        print(" both are nonetype type",type(a))
    elif a!=b:
        print("values of both are not same",a,b)
    else:
        print("values of both are same but not nonetype",type(b),type(b))
```

output:
1)a=Nonetype,b=Nonetype,**answer**:both are nonetype type 
2)a=Nonetype,b=3, **answer**:values of both are not same None 3
3)a=3,b=3, **answer**:values of both are same but not nonetype